# How does bert produce variable output shape?

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, bert

Suppose if I provide a list of sentences:

```
['I like python',
 'I am learning python', # longest sentence of length 4 tokens
 'Python is simple']
```

Bert will produce an output of (3 * 4+2 * 768).
Because there were 3 sentences, 4 max tokens, 768 hidden states.

Suppose if I provide another list of sentences:

```
['I like python',
 'I am learning python',
 'Python is simple',
 'Python is fun to learn' # 5 tokens
]
```

The new embedding output would be (4 * 5+2 * 768).

I understand that dim[0] becomes 4 because there is now 4 sentences instead. This is achieved by increasing the rows of the tensor(batch size) during tensor computation.

I also understand that dim[1] becomes 5+2 because the max number of token is number 5 and there is [CLS] and [SEP] tokens at the start and end.
I also understand that there is a **padding mechanism** that accepts up to a **max_position_embeddings=512** for bert model.

---

What I want to ask is:

- during computation, does bert pad all the values after 5th element with zeros and process with computation using a input of (4 * 512) (4 sentences, 512 max tokens).
- then after computation from the output of (4 * 512 * 768), the tensor is trimmed to output: (4 * 5+2 * 768).
- if the above assumptions is true, isn't it a huge waste of resources, since majority of the 512 tokens are not attention-required.
- I read about the **attention_mask** matrix that tells the model which are the tokens needed for computation, but I don't understand how does **attention_mask** achieve this; when the architecture of the model is initialised with N dimensional inputs, how does attention_mask help during computation to ignore/avoid the computation of the attention-masked elements?
- which part of the bert model explicitly restrict the output to (4 * 5+2 * 768)?